# Adding Meta Box to Specific Submenu Page

Tags: metabox, sub-menu, add-submenu-page

I've created this page:

```
function wpdocs_register_my_setting() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=task',
        'View Tasks',
        'View Tasks',
        'manage_options',
        'view-tasks',
        'view_tasks_submenu_page_callback'
    );
}

function view_tasks_submenu_page_callback() {
    // html
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_setting' );
```

And I want to add a meta box to this page only.

```
function cd_meta_box_add() {
    add_meta_box( 'in-progress-metabox', 'In Progress', 'render_task_in_progress_metabox', 'task', 'normal', 'high' );
}
function render_task_in_progress_metabox() {
    // html
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
```

But I cannot seem to find the correct answer for this. Again, I only want to add this meta box to this specific page. I've seen people talk about needing to use `do_meta_boxes` but it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: please complete your code, how do you create your page?

Comment: What? The code is complete... you don't need to see the HTML output of the actual page.... that has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @dcolumbu, from your snippet and explanation it is not very obvious when do you want to add it and when not.

Comment: I think it's extremely obvious. I've created an admin page and I want to add a meta box to that page only... I shown the code for both the page and the meta box, but I don't know how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this you want to go with [Wordpress Setting API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

If you prefer meta box. You have to add a `do_action` in your function which render the page (`view_tasks_submenu_page_callback`).

`do_action( 'add_meta_boxes', $hook_id );`

And add `do_meta_boxes($hook_id, $context, null)` where you want your meta boxes appear.

replace `$hook_id` by the fourth parameter of add_meta_box function.

Comment: But there is no `ID` given for this page.

Comment: I edited the answer for more clear.